# Has the way of debugging changed in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have done a simple test with this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject.inventory</groupId>
    <artifactId>inventory</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>inventory</name>
    <description>Project to control inventory</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And this startup Class:

```
package com.myproject.inventory;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class InventoryApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(InventoryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

With version 2.7.2, debug with `spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.fork=false -f pom.xml` it's working fine stopping in a breakpoint on `SpringApplication.run(InventoryApplication.class, args);` line. But with version 3.0.3 of `spring-boot-starter-parent`, it is not working.

Does someone know if this has changed in Spring Boot 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for running your application in Maven's JVM was deprecated in Spring Boot 2.7 and [removed in Spring Boot 3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#running-your-application-in-the-maven-process). You can use `-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments` to enable debugging in the JVM that runs your app. There's an [example of this in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.debug):

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

Comment: What have I done wrong?
I added ```-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments``` to my run configurations in Intellij. I have updated the pom file plugin ```<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>``` with 

<configuration>
<jvmArguments>
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
</jvmArguments>
</configuration>

I created a remote jmv debug tab with the above cmdline args / port. 

However, it still won't build using the command above.

Error injecting: org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type RunMojo not present

Comment: I can't see the connection between this question and answer and "Type RunMojo not present". If I were you, I would ask a new question that includes the full stacktrace of the failure and some steps to reproduce.

Comment: Just resolved the issue.
Update pom.xml with
<plugins>
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
    <jvmArguments>
    -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
     </jvmArguments>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
In Intellij:
Create separate run config Remote JVM debug
Run service normally 
Select debug for new Remote JVM debug configuration.
I was then able to hit breakpoints when I triggered them from Postman